# Display info from two tables in a details view when a specific ID is chosen by the user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am creating mvc application in vb.net and I am trying to use a ViewModel to display information about two Tables from SQL.

So far I can successfully display the information for one Table but I am unsure how to display the information from the other table.

The IssueTable is being displayed when the user selects its ID, but the table that I want to display with it is the CommentsTable.

There is a one-to-many relationship between the IssueTable and the CommentsTable, so for example I want to display the IssueSummary and for each IssueID that matches the IssueID in the commentsTable I want to display the commentBody which will mean each issueSummary would have multiple comments.

So far this is what I have got.

I created a class like this:

```
Namespace IssueTracker
    Public Class IssueComments
        Public cTable As CommentTable 'CommentTable in SQL database
        Public iTable As IssueTable 'IssueTable in SQL database
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then in the controller I got this:

```
Dim IssTable As IssueTable = dbServer.IssueTables.Find(id) 'getting the ID of the selected issue

Dim iss As New IssueTable() With {
    .IssueID = IssTable.IssueID,
    .IssueKey = IssTable.IssueKey,
    .IssueTypeID = IssTable.IssueTypeID,
    .priorityID = IssTable.priorityID,
    .IssueSummary = IssTable.IssueSummary,
    .IssueDescription = IssTable.IssueDescription,
    .Created = IssTable.Created,
    .Updated = IssTable.Updated
} ' This will display the information about the specific issue crrectly
```

Here I am trying to display the information about the comments:

```
Dim comment As New CommentTable() With {
    .CommentID = cTable.CommentID,
    .CommentBody = cTable.CommentBody
} 'Will not display anything as it is not correctly connected with issueTable

Dim viewModelC As New IssueTracker.IssueComments() With {
    .cTable = comment,
    .iTable = iss
} 'Here I create the variable viewModel the return it in the view 

Return View(viewModelC)
```

I am trying to connect the two tables like this:

```
 Dim viewModel = From c In dbServer.CommentTables Join i In dbServer.IssueTables On c.IssueID Equals i.IssueID Where (c.IssueID = i.IssueID)
Select New IssueTracker.IssueComments With {.cTable = c, .iTable = i}
```

How can I properly display all comments for each issueID that is in the commentsTable that is equal to the issueID in the IssueTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the issues+comments sent to the view at the same time, don't try to combine them in the controller, create a new class (under ViewModels) that contains properties for both lists and send them both to the view and handle it there.

```
Namespace IssueTracker.ViewModels
    Public Class IssueCommentsViewModel
        Public Issues As List(Of Issue)
        Public Comments As List(Of Comment)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then, in the view, handle finding the correct data, eg:

```
<table>
    @For Each issue In Model.Issues
        Dim comments = Model.Comments.Where(c=>c.IssueID == issue.IssueID))
        @<tr>
            <th>@issue.Summary</th>
        <tr>

        @For Each comment In comments
            @<tr>
                <td>@comment.CommentBody</td>
            </tr>
        Next
    Next
<table>
```

(attempted to make this Razor vb.net syntax - hopefully the concept can be seen, rather than syntax issues)

Edit: to populate the viewmodel, taking your existing code from the question:

```
Dim model = New ViewModel()
model.Issues = dbServer.IssueTables
model.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables
Return View(model)
```

---

A re-look at the code and it looks like you are only returning a single issue, so updated:

```
Namespace IssueTracker.ViewModels
    Public Class IssueCommentsViewModel
        Public Issue As IssueTable
        Public Comments As List(Of CommentTable)
    End Class
End Namespace 


Dim model = New ViewModel()
model.Issues = dbServer.IssueTables.Find(id)
model.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables.Where(x=>x.IssueID Equals id) ' this doesn't look like VB to me, so change accordingly
Return View(model)

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Model.Issue.Summary</th>
    <tr>

    @For Each comment In Model.Comments
        @<tr>
            <td>@comment.CommentBody</td>
        </tr>
    Next
<table>
```

---

An an aside: if you have a lot of issues+comments, then you should look at showing just the issues in the view, then using ajax callbacks to load comments dynamically based on user action (eg clicking an 'expand' icon)

Comment: Yes, you'd use `@ModelType namespace.class` (from my example `@ModelType IssueTracker.ViewModels.IssueCommentsViewModel`) - the specifics would depend on where you put the class in the project/namespaces.

Comment: depends on the error...  but yes, I'd create an instance with `Dim model As New IssuecommentsViewModel()` and populate the two properties with the two DB lookups and `Return View(model)`

Comment: model.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables.Where(Function(x) x.IssueID = id) comes up with the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Table]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Table]'.", do you know the problem?

Comment: There is a problem with "model.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables.Where(x=>x.IssueID Equals id)" it is not working because model.Comments is a list and dbserver.Comments is a Table so it is giving me an error do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Just change the type of the ViewModel to match, you can likely still use `For Each` if it's IEnumerable

Comment: yes the for each is ok its the model.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables.Where(x=>x.IssueID Equals id)  in the controller that is not working.  Because model.Comments is a list of commentTable it cannot equal dbserver.CommentTable so I get an error casting it there I need it to equal a list of comment tables where the id's match do you know how to do that?

Comment: Change the ViewModel definition:  `Public Comments As List(Of dbserver.CommentTable)` .  The Where clause just returns the same type as the source list.  I don't know what your dbServer is so can't really help with that part - but the issue has a .Find(id) so maybe you have or can add a .Find(expression).

Answer (score 1):

you can use an ajax call when user click an item,pass the item pk to find the second table data,and put the result on page.
for example,you have 2 div on page,1st show the iss table,when user click an item in the table,begin an ajax call to another controller/action,pass the item pk,the action return a view without layout,in the view ,display comments table.put the result in 2nd div by js.
there is a eazy way,add a

`@Ajax.ActionLink("comments","actionName","ControllerName",new{id=item.id},new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="div2"})`

in each of row in your 1st table.the "div2" is you 2nd div's id.
be sure you refrence jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your page.and it will work
there are 2 controller/action 1st get the iss table data and return view.
2nd need a param to recive the iss table pk,and get the comment table data in this iss
i'm hard to read vb.net code,hope this can help you

Comment: This looks like it would work but ajax is unnecessary for my application as the way I add comments is going through JIRA and then redirects back but I upvoted as I still think it was a good answer